# matching pictureboxes with values

Tags: c#, arrays, image, indexing, match

This is my first post ever and I really need help.

My problem is that i'm creating a slot machine game using C# , I've made everything work, except for the values. My idea is that I need to match the picture with a value of it , lets say the (Picture Joker = 100 points ).  Is there anyway to do that using a function so I can call it later on throughout the program.

I have tried to use this kind of function:

```
void ImageValues (int RollResult)
       {
           switch (RollResult)
           {
           case 0 :
           TempTotal += 100;
           break;
           case 1 :
           TempTotal += 225;
           break;
           case 2 :
           TempTotal += 550;
           break;
            case 3 :
           TempTotal += 775;
           break;
           case 4 :
           TempTotal += 1000;
           break;
       }
       }
```

but when I call the function I have to define which case I want to use. There is no way I can predefine a picture to a value, my friend told me to try to match indexes, like the index of the picture from the:

```
int[] PictureValues = new int[]{100, 225, 550, 775, 1000};
```

to the pictureboxes array:

```
PictureBox[] PictureboxArray = new PictureBox[5];
```

Is there  a way to do that ? Thanks for the help.

EDIT 1 , the images are assigned like this

```
PictureboxArray[0] = pbxK;
        PictureboxArray[1] = pbxQueen;
        PictureboxArray[2] = pbxKing;
        PictureboxArray[3] = pbxJoker;
        PictureboxArray[4] = pbxAce;
        Rollimage[0] = Properties.Resources.K;
        Rollimage[1] = Properties.Resources.Queen;
        Rollimage[2] = Properties.Resources.King;
        Rollimage[3] = Properties.Resources.Joker;
        Rollimage[4] = Properties.Resources.Ace;
        pbxK.Image = Rollimage[0];
        pbxQueen.Image = Rollimage[1];
        pbxKing.Image = Rollimage[2];
        pbxJoker.Image = Rollimage[3];
        pbxAce.Image = Rollimage[4];
```

Comment: How do you tell if the picture is a joker?

Comment: i got 5 pictureboxes, each pictureboxes random the 5 pictures , so i was using case statement saying if any of the pictureboxes has joker then add to the temptotal this kind of value

Comment: Post the code of your check if the picturebox is a joker.

Comment: i dont actually have a check for pictures :/ it is random picture and depending on the picture add the value to temptotal , thats what im trying to do

Comment: How do you tell your pictures apart? You compare names, you have them enumed, how exactly you know if you have a joker or any other picture in your picturebox?

Comment: @Gnqz i added an edit to show how each picture is presented and linked

Answer (score 0):

Each picture box control has a property called `Tag`, if you click your picture box you see it in the property window. You can store your pre-defined score values in the tag and retrieve them where necessary.

According to the property window a Tag is: `"User-defined data associated with the object"`

Comment: but im not assigning the pictures in the picture boxes , im actually assigning them using code , so it can be random pictures. look at my edit  :D

Comment: `PictureboxArray[1].tag = 100, PictureboxArray[2].tag= 50` etc

Comment: im not assigning the values to the pictureboxes im trying to assign them to the images themselves, like the `Properties.Resources.K` = value' i know it does work like that but thats what im trying to do

Comment: `Rollimage[0] = Properties.Resources.K;` so `RollImage[0].Tag` you cant access or it doesn' t exist?

Comment: i can actually have access to it haha i made a subprogram with the values and then call it when the picturebox stopping, it does show the in temptotal

Comment: Is your problem solved or not I didn't get it from the above comment!

Comment: im trying @Gnqz solution which is using a dictionary , ill give you guys a shout if i did

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `int` array, you can use a `Dictionary<string,int>` with the name of the card and the value.

```
enum Pics
{
   "K","Queen","King","Joker","Ace"
}
```

You can enumerate the names of the cards and branch to a particular case using the name of the card and add the value to `TempTotal`.

```
switch(RollResult)
{
     case Pics.K:
     TempTotal += picsDictionary["K"];
     break;
    //...
}
```

Comment: okay i made the dictionary and added all the names of the picture + their values , now how should i call it or how should i assign the names to the images so they are paired ??

Comment: i cant seem to make it work , im running into errors all the time :( this is really frustrating

Comment: lots of error i have no idea how to call the dictionary or even how to make an enum and link it to the dictionary and everytime im using enum in the switch , its asking for cast or something like that :(